# TypedArray not working

Tags: android, xml-attribute, xml-layout, typedarray

I'm learning about custom components and i'm having some trouble with custom xml attributes.
My custom component extends LinearLayout and in the constructor(`public Custom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`)i'm inflating a xml layout(2 Buttons and 1 EditText). 
I also declared in `values/attrs` this custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Custom">
        <attr name="initValue" format="integer" />
        <attr name="stepSize" format="integer" />
        <attr name="maxValue" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In the constructor after i inflate the layout i'm trying to read the custom attributes like this:

```
   if (attrs != null) {
                TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                        R.styleable.Custom, 0, 0);
                setInitValue(ta.getInt(R.styleable.Custom_initValue, 0));
                setStepSize(ta.getInt(R.styleable.Custom_stepSize, 1));
                setMaxValue(ta.getInt(R.styleable.Custom_maxValue, 5));         
                ta.recycle();
            }
```

Now i try to test this custom component by adding it to a xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <here.is.my.package.Custom android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        initValue="2" maxValue="7" stepSize="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This doesn't work and i get only the default values (0, 1, 5). Am i missing something or this is normal behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, i figured the answer for my question. The answer was that i simply used my custom xml attributes with no namespace and android just ignored them and gave me the default values. After adding my namespace:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:customAttribute="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/gere.is.my.package"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <here.is.my.package.Custom android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            customAttribute:initValue="2" customAttribute:maxValue="7" customAttribute:stepSize="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

everything worked.

Comment: Dear same showing issue for me...I created an CustomTextView and create an seprate xml layout, so any one can use it just by use <include>...but when I tried to fetch custom value attribute..it's giving default value only...any suggestion.

Comment: @Shubh Please post a new question providing all the details of the problem.

Comment: it working for me....did project cleanup following restart workspace again..and it started working...thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle projects, use

> xmlns:customView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

this works for me!